# Using dlib trained object detector in Python

Tags: python, c++, dlib

I'm working on Python. I've been using dlib's function `dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()` to detect frontal faces, and I'm now using the tutorial on http://dlib.net/fhog_object_detector_ex.cpp.html to train my own object detector. However, this is trained in C++.

How can I use the trained classifier (which I believe is called `face_detector.svm`) and use it on Python?

(A better question might be how to train dlib's HOG in Python entirely, but it's less crucial.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python example where you can train and test object detector can be found here - 
[github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/python_examples/train_object_detector.py](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/python_examples/train_object_detector.py)